# solr plugin for symfony?

Tags: symfony1, solr

with symfony using doctrine is very easy cause its fully integrated into the framework.

i wonder if there is a possibility to integrate solr with symfony too (eg, via plugin?)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2: [tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin) and [sfSolrPlugin](http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfSolrPlugin). The second is a fork of the excellent sfLucenePlugin which works with sf1.0 and sf1.1, and although it doesn't have much exposure, it is stable. Check the full [README](http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfSolrPlugin/branches/sf1.2/README) for details of its use.

Comment: thanks. have u tried them both? if so, which one would u recommend?

Comment: I've tried sfLucenePlugin for sf1.0 and sf1.1 and was very happy with it. As I don't use Doctrine I've not used either of the above, instead building my own from ZSL directly, but if sfSolrPlugin is as good as sfLucenePlugin, then that would be my recommendation. Ask around though, as there may be others.

Comment: I've had good results so far with tjSolrDoctrineBehaviorPlugin. The dev is also responsive to email questions.

Comment: They is a plugin compatible with symfony 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article here to explain how to easyly make a powerfull search engine with symfony : http://leny-bernard.com/en/show/article/un-moteur-de-recherche-ultra-performant, you can ask me some questions on my website with the comment form